# How to create clustered bar graph based on one of the columns?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create a bar graph using the data below, and I want to do binning based on the category provided in the first column, I am looking for a feature like hue in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with gnuplot.

The csv file I am using looks as follows (snippet):

```
DS_TYPE, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4
type1, 24, 20000, 15, 20
type2, 48, 20000, 20, 60
type3, 96, 20000, 25, 90
type3, 144, 200000, 30, 110
...
```

The fig I wanted is a bar chart using arg1 as x-axis, arg4 as y-axis, DS_TYPE (there are only 3 types) as hue.

Currently I only see solutions by adding more columns to this csv file, (arg1_type1, arg1_type2...and so on). I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set datafile separator ','
    plot './test.csv' using 2:3:xtic(1) with boxes
EOFMarker
```

I read similar code like this from the gnuplot [manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf) on (rowstacked) histogram, but I cannot find a solution for bar chart:

```
Each cluster of boxes is derived from a single row of the input data file. It is common in such input files that
the first element of each row is a label. Labels from this column may be placed along the x-axis underneath
the appropriate cluster of boxes with the xticlabels option to using.
```

I tried to use similar code for bar chart (I am not sure whether I understand it correctly, I think if I use xtic(1), it means I will use the first column for binning), using the code described above, but it didn't work.

The graph I am looking for (I did it with seaborn) is like this:

[image]

Note:

In this example there are only 3 types, but I am looking for a binning approach where it can handle cases when the number of type is N(unknown).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your script. How many different `types` do you have? Are they named `type1`, `type2`, ... `typeN` or do they have other "real" names in your real data?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So far I thought you want to do a scatter xy-plot (column2 and column3) with colors depending on column 1. Since you are now mentioning histograms and your script is `with boxes`, I'm getting confused and maybe you want to sum up column 3 for each of the 3 different types?

Comment: @theozh Sorry I intended to do a bar chart at first, but i made it confusing by providing a scatter point example from seaborn.

Comment: ok, I'm still confused... My next guess: do you want 3 (or in general N) histograms, i.e. distribution of values (however of which column? column2 or column3?) for each type next to each other? Please edit your question and add a handsketch illustrating what you are looking for.

Comment: @theozh Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question again, and hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification and illustrative example of OP, here is an attempt to get to the desired plot.

- create unique lists of your keywords for the items and the group. The sequence will be in the order of first occurrence in the data. Unfortunately, gnuplot has no internal sorting feature. Alphanumerical sorting would require some external tools or very weird workarounds.
- plot the data in two nested loops by filtering the data accordingly.
- add the legend by using the ternary operator (check `help ternary`).
- add a single xtic centered per group, independent if there are odd or even numbers of items.

This solution is not very obvious and maybe there is a simpler approach using the plotting style histogram. I would love to learn about a simpler solution.

**Script:**

```
### plot grouped box chart 
reset session

$Data <<EOD
DS_TYPE, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4
type1, 24, 20000, 15, 20
type2, 48, 20000, 20, 60
type3, 96, 20000, 25, 90
type3, 144, 200000, 30, 110
EOD

set datafile separator comma
myColors = "0x3a7ca4 0xe38a3f 0x439549"
myColor(i) = int(word(myColors,i))

colI  = 1    # column item
colG  = 3    # column group
colY  = 5    # column y-value
uniq1 = uniq2 = ''
addToList(list,s) = list.( int(sum [_i=1:words(list)] word(list,_i) eq s) ? '' : ' '.s)
stats $Data u (uniq1=addToList(uniq1,strcol(colI)), uniq2=addToList(uniq2,strcol(colG))) skip 1 nooutput

gap = 1
xPos(i,j) = (i-1) + (j-1)*words(uniq1) + j*gap
set boxwidth 1.0
set style fill solid 1.0
set key noautotitle top left
set tics out
set yrange[0:]
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0

plot for [i=1:words(uniq1)] for [j=1:words(uniq2)] $Data u (xPos(i,j)): \
     (word(uniq1,i) eq strcol(colI) && word(uniq2,j) eq strcol(colG) ? column(colY) : NaN): \
     (myColor(i)) w boxes lc rgb var ti j==1?word(uniq1,i):'', \
     for [j=1:words(uniq2)] '+' u ((xPos(1,j)+xPos(words(uniq1),j))/2.):(NaN):xtic(word(uniq2,j)) every ::::0
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Two more questions 1) if there is a way to automatically do the binning process(i.e. when the number of types is unknown) 2) how do I add the labels for different colors? (in this case, red for type1, green for type2..)

Comment: @Rubujubi which columns do you want to use for binning? Column2 for the x-value and column3 for summing up the y-values. And the type in column1 for 3 (or N) different histograms/distributions? Could you please provide more lines of example data?

Comment: @Rubujubi so, problem solved? Question answered?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Yes this solved my problem. Sorry for the late reply.